# Need to show index.html in my url

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Need to know how to show the full URL of my website, I would need to pass:
www.ejemplo.com.ar to www.ejemplo.com.ar/**index.html**
I've tried all types of redirect and rewrite, but none worked out. I hope you can help me.

Over Apache2

Comment: Posting your example would help get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty easy solution, a search would have revealed it easily. Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ejemplo\.com\.ar$
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It not resolve my problem, beacuse the problem was in the config of angularjs; but your answer was helpfull!